# AngularJS: too big amount of listeners on view and long loading time of the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, memory-leaks

I have issue with Angular view when joining the view second time.

**Input:**

- View loads list of 1500 items
- All 1500 items displayed in table with `ng-repeat` and filter
- No `$watch` used in the view

**Problem description:**

1. When first time join the view it loads fine and works fine no
   performance issues.
2. When leave view after step 1 it takes 5sec-10sec
3. When join the view second time after step 2 it takes 30sec and 99% of that time spend for scripting. After profiling this step it shows > 20000 listeners.

**Questions:**

1. Any suggestions what can be cause of performance problem on step (3)?
2. Interesting to know how much data good to display with `ng-repeat`?

[image]

Comment: Use `track by $index` phrase whenever you are using `ng-repeat`. It will improve the performance. Are you using `track by $index` ?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Also, if you don't need watching on `ng-repeat` output, you can use one-time binding to avoid all those watchers https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code we can't give a definitive answer but the problem probably lies in the fact you render so many items.

Every time you `ng-bind` something it will create a `$watch`, because of the big data set (with probably multiple bindings) your watchers will be extremely high. In order to overcome this you can use something that uses virtualisation (instead of rendering everything, only render what fits the screen) such as [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/).